# cakephp: authen function auto direct to user/login

Tags: cakephp, authentication, cakephp-2.1

i am beginning with cakephp framework, i use auth to create a login form, at my appcontroller i add:

```
class AppController extends Controller {
    public $components = array('Auth', 'Cookie');
    public function beforeFilter(){
        $this->Auth->authenticate = array(
                'Form' => array(
                    'userModel' => 'User',
                    'fields' => array('name' => 'name', 'password' => 'password'),
                )
            );
            $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'TestOnlineSystem', 'action' => 'P001');
            $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'TestOnlineSystem', 'action' => 'index');
            $this->Auth->loginError = 'Failed to login';
            $this->Auth->authError = ' ';           
    }   
}
```

but when i run TestOnlineSystem/P001 it auto redirect to users/login anh show message net controller usercontroller. How can i fix it, P001 is my login page

Comment: Just wondering (don't know if this makes a difference); Why perform all those settings inside the 'beforeFilter()', and not just inside the '$components' array as described in the manual? (http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#configuring-authentication-handlers).

Comment: +1 for thinking outside-conventions on your controller names... oh wait... ;)

Comment: (Please clarify:  "...show message net controller usercontroller."

Answer (score 0):

I agree with thaJeztah, try the standard config from http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html :

```
public $components = array(
    'Auth' => array(
        'loginAction' => array(
            'controller' => 'TestOnlineSystem',
            'action' => 'P001',
            'plugin' => 'users'
        )
    )
);
```

and get rid of your beforeFilter().